# how to convert java object to plain string in j2me Bluetooth application?

Tags: java, string, object, java-me

I'm making a j2me Bluetooth application. I'm also new in java world. Where I have to display a Bluetooth service name to the user. So far it seems all is working correctly except service name. I verified my Bluetooth server is advertising service name correctly by other client (done by qt). I tried as follows:-

```
          public void commandAction(Command command, Item item) {
    if (item == deviceChoiceGroup) {
        if (command == servicesDiscoverCommand) {
            if(deviceList.size()==0) {
                return; 
            }

            UUID[] searchList = new UUID[1];
            searchList[0] = new UUID("11111111111111111111111111111111",false);

            int[] attrSet = new int[1];
            attrSet[0] = 0x100;

            RemoteDevice currentDevice = 
                (RemoteDevice) deviceList.elementAt(
                    getDeviceChoiceGroup().getSelectedIndex());

            if(currentDevice == null) { 
                return; 
            }

            try {
                transactionID = bluetoothDiscoveryAgent.searchServices(
                        new int[] {0x100}, searchList, currentDevice, this);
                printToForm("Start services under L2CAP searching...");
                form.addCommand(cancelServicesDiscoverCommand);
            } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
                //TODO: write handler code
            }
        }
    }
}


public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] serviceRecords){
    if (serviceRecords.length>0 && serviceRecords!=null)
    {
        connectionURL=serviceRecords[0].getConnectionURL(0, false);

        int[] ids=serviceRecords[0].getAttributeIDs();  
        DataElement ServiceName=serviceRecords[0].getAttributeValue(ids[1]);           
        // tried to convert objedct to string. 
        String str = (ServiceName.getValue()).toString();
        // out is put is like java.util.vector$1@3c60cd14c
        printToForm("#Service name: "+str); 

        printToForm("The Service name is: "+ServiceName.getValue());

    }
}
```

"DataElement.getValue()" which returns object. Thus I can see service name as "java.util.vector$1@3c60cd14c". I tried to convert object to string as "String str = (ServiceName.getValue()).toString();" It doesn't convert correctly.

So how to convert object to string. So that I could see the service name in plain text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing the result : `java.util.vector$1@3c60cd14c` i guess the returned object's type is Vector.

So try to cast to the Vector and iterate through it to get the values.

```
Iterator itr = serviceName.getValue().iterator();//do something here
System.out.println("Iterating through Vector elements...");
while(itr.hasNext())
      System.out.println(itr.next());
```